# android, drawerLayout: closeDrawer и closeDrawers не работает

Tags: android

Не получается программно закрыть DrawerLayout. Не работают методы closeDrawer и closeDrawers.
Пробовал так:

```
binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END, true)
binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(binding.navView)
binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(binding.drawerLayout)
binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawers()
```

Не понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

у меня прям сейчас есть проект и есть отдельная кнопка, которая должна закрывать Drawer. внутри этой кнопки у меня прописано

```
mainDrawer.close()
```

все работает.

Comment: binding.drawerLayout.close() - вот так написал. 38 строка - получаю ошибку такую

Comment: at com.mobile_solutions.clean_me.layers.presentation.FragmentActivity.profile(FragmentActivity.kt:38)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT

Comment: У androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout - android:layout_gravity="end", что мне нужно сделать?

Comment: @VasiliyK для начала полностью сделать его рабочим на ayout_gravity="start". с end'ом свои заморочки. вполне возможно, что на них и натыкаетесь